# On Android 2.3.5, NullPointerException when enableForegroundDispatch(...)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, nfc

I have implemented the NFC foreground dispatch in my Activity. The code works fine when I run on **Android 4.2.1** device (Samsung Galaxy Nexus). **But** when I run on **Android 2.3.5** device (HTC Desire S), there is a **NullPointerException**. Here is some code of my Activity, exception is thrown in `onResume()` part:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
   private NfcAdapter mAdapter; 
   private IntentFilter[] intentFilterArray;
   private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
   private String[][] techArray;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

      mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);

    intentFilterArray = new IntentFilter[]{intentFilter};
    techArray = new String[][]{new String[]{NdefFormatable.class.getName(), NfcA.class.getName()}};
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
      //NullPointerException here,because mAdapter is Null, why?    
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFilterArray, techArray);   
   }

   @Override
   public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
   }
   ...

}
```

On **Android 2.3.5** device, (LogCat shows me) the **NullPointerException** happens in `onResume()` when call `mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(…)`. I checked, it is because `mAdapter` is **null**.  Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `getDefaultAdapter` method returns null if there is no NFC on your phone like explains on [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#getDefaultAdapter(android.content.Context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#getDefaultAdapter%28android.content.Context%29)